# How to use Swagger to test the return of a base64 serialized PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, base64, swagger

We already use swagger to test our API but it's always json coming in and out.
Next week we are tasked to build some reports in PDF format but send it to the front end in a base64 text format.

My dream is to use swagger to just send the parameters (json) and auto open a visualization of the result.

I imagine I can build a middleware and tell swagger to return to it but I'm clueless in how to achieve this.

I guess it's not relevant but we are building our backend in C#.

In short: How to open/visualize a base64 encoded PDF from swagger?

Comment: Assuming that by "Swagger" you mean "Swagger UI" - PDF rendering if not supported out-of-the-box, but [this thread](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4665) has some suggestions for Swagger UI v. 3.x.